# how to get clipboard data in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, clipboard, clipboarddata

I was actually looking to get the content of clipboard using angular JS to simulate a copy paste thing.

Comment: Highly recommend [angular-zeroclipboard](https://github.com/lisposter/angular-zeroclipboard), it is better documented than `ng-clip`. Also I failed to make `ng-clip` working.

Comment: ng-clip depends on ZeroClipboard (at least in some modes of operation), and made it much easier to integrate "Copy to Clipboard" functionality in my case. I followed [these few steps](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-clip#usage) to get it working.

Answer (score 8):

I created a directive for copy to clipboard which is using the [document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method.

**Directive**

```
(function() {
app.directive('copyToClipboard',  function ($window) {
        var body = angular.element($window.document.body);
        var textarea = angular.element('<textarea/>');
        textarea.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            opacity: '0'
        });

        function copy(toCopy) {
            textarea.val(toCopy);
            body.append(textarea);
            textarea[0].select();

            try {
                var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
                if (!successful) throw successful;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("failed to copy", toCopy);
            }
            textarea.remove();
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (e) {
                    copy(attrs.copyToClipboard);
                });
            }
        }
    })
}).call(this);
```

**Html**

```
<button  copy-to-clipboard="Copy Me!!!!" class="button">COPY</button>
```

Comment: How might one copy something other than "Copy Me!!!!" - such as , say, the contents of a textarea?

Comment: In Controller, use a scope variable 
$scope.copyMe = '';
and use this var in the textarea value as following.
<textarea value="copyMe">
and use the same var in the copy-to-clipboard as following:
<button  copy-to-clipboard="copyMe" class="button">COPY</button>

Comment: When I use this code, textarea.val(toCopy) doesn't append anything into the textarea (my toCopy is text html). When I append it to the body, it actually appends [object Object]. Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: @MohammedSafwan Can you please share your code and also are you using Angular 1.5?

Comment: @nutboltu I am using `AngularJS v1.2.20`. Is there any version constraint for using this code snippet?

Comment: @MohammedSafwan not really. can you please share your piece of code?

Comment: Just make it <textarea value="{{copyMe}}">  and it will work for scope variables as well. By the way its the quickest solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

here's a concise version I use -

```
function copyToClipboard(data) {
    angular.element('<textarea/>')
        .css({ 'opacity' : '0', 'position' : 'fixed' })
        .text(data)
        .appendTo(angular.element($window.document.body))
        .select()
        .each(function() { document.execCommand('copy') })
        .remove();
}
```

Comment: Sure looks concise. I wish I could figure out it works. Doesn't copy for me.

Comment: `angular.element()` doesn't include the function `appendTo()` unless you include the whole *jQuery* library.  Same goes for `select()`

Answer (score 2):

BTW, if using Angular to copy to clipboard with a Chrome Packaged App, do the following:

1. Add "clipboardRead" and "clipboardWrite" to the "permissions" in the manifest.json.
2. use ng-click in your view to feed the value to the controller $scope, like: data-ng-click="copyUrlToClipboard(file.webContentLink)"
3. Put a function in your controller like:

   ```
   $scope.copyUrlToClipboard =  function(url) {
       var copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
       copyFrom.textContent = url;
       var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       body.appendChild(copyFrom);
       copyFrom.select();
       document.execCommand('copy');
       body.removeChild(copyFrom);
       this.flashMessage('over5');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I used angular-clipboard feature[1] which uses new Selection API and Clipboard API available in the latest browsers.

First we have to install angular-clipboard lib, i'm using bower.

```
$ bower install angular-clipboard --save
```

To import the module use following in html.

```
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-clipboard/angular-clipboard.js"></script>
```

To set values to element using $scope in controller

```
$scope.textToCopy = 'Testing clip board';
```

Load the clipboard module using,

```
angular.module('testmodule', ['angular-clipboard']);
```

This works for Chrome 43+, Firefox 41+, Opera 29+ and IE10+.

Its simple & worked fine.

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-clipboard

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach:

I need to copy & paste text between windows, so I used [this](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) to save (copy) the data to local storage. Then, in the other window, I load it out of local storage, using the same key, and I can then 'paste' is as I like.