# AngularJS copy to clipboard

Tags: angularjs, clipboard

Is there a way to make a copy button with a copy function that will copy all the contents of a modal and you can paste it to notepad

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get clipboard data in angular JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028578/how-to-get-clipboard-data-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 30):

I needed this functionality in my `Controller`, as the text to be copied is dynamic, here's my simple function based on the code in the [ngClipboard](https://github.com/nico-val/ngClipboard) module:

```
function share() {
    var text_to_share = "hello world";

    // create temp element
    var copyElement = document.createElement("span");
    copyElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text_to_share));
    copyElement.id = 'tempCopyToClipboard';
    angular.element(document.body.append(copyElement));

    // select the text
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(copyElement);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    // copy & cleanup
    document.execCommand('copy');
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    copyElement.remove();
}
```

**P.S.**
You're welcome to add a comment now telling me how bad it is to [manipulate DOM from a Controller](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/).

Comment: "how bad it is to manipulate DOM from a Controller" - Like most other "best practices" in Software Engineering imo, there are occassionally situations where it makes sense to break the best practice - I think this answer is great!

Comment: ALWAYS! gives me [Object object] in the clipborad...
[My Text is a JSON, but I modified the appendChild line to:

copyElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSONstringify(text_to_share)));

So that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: @Hobbamok comment out the last two lines (cleanup) and check your dev-console how that copyElement looks like and what does it contain

Comment: if you `createElement("pre")` instead of `span`, then you can copy/paste pretty-printed JSON (so that your pretty printed JSON doesn't get mangled into single line when assigned to text node within `span`). Tested in Chrome.

Comment: or textarea instead of span

Answer (score 12):

If you have jquery support use this directive

```
.directive('copyToClipboard', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.click(function () {
                    if (attrs.copyToClipboard) {
                        var $temp_input = $("<input>");
                        $("body").append($temp_input);
                        $temp_input.val(attrs.copyToClipboard).select();
                        document.execCommand("copy");
                        $temp_input.remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Html

```
<a href="" copy-to-clipboard="Text to copy">Copy text</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

if you don't want to add a new library to your project, and you create it by your self, here is a simple, easy solution:

note: I created it with promise functionality (which is awesome)

here is `CopyToClipboard.js module file`

```
angular.module('CopyToClipboard', [])
        .controller('CopyToClipboardController', function () {

        })
        .provider('$copyToClipboard', [function () {

            this.$get = ['$q', '$window', function ($q, $window) {
                var body = angular.element($window.document.body);
                var textarea = angular.element('<textarea/>');
                textarea.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    opacity: '0'
                });
                return {
                    copy: function (stringToCopy) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        deferred.notify("copying the text to clipboard");
                        textarea.val(stringToCopy);
                        body.append(textarea);
                        textarea[0].select();

                        try {
                            var successful = $window.document.execCommand('copy');
                            if (!successful) throw successful;
                            deferred.resolve(successful);
                        } catch (err) {
                            deferred.reject(err);
                            //window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", toCopy);
                        } finally {
                            textarea.remove();
                        }
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                };
            }];
        }]);
```

that's it, thanks to https://gist.github.com/JustMaier/6ef7788709d675bd8230

now let's use it

```
angular.module('somthing')
   .controller('somthingController', function ($scope, $copyToClipboard) {
       // you are free to do what you want
            $scope.copyHrefToClipboard = function() {
            $copyToClipboard.copy(/*string to be coppied*/$scope.shareLinkInfo.url).then(function () {
                //show some notification
            });
        };
   }
```

and finally the HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-clipboard" data-ng-click="copyHrefToClipboard($event)"></i>
```

hope this saves your time

Answer (score 6):

`document.execCommand` is now deprecated. Instead you can do:

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-copy" ng-click="copyToClipboard('some text to copy')"></i>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.copyToClipboard = function(string) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(string)
        .then(console.log('copied!'));          
}
```

Comment: This one is the right answer!! 

`document.execCommand` is not working now

Comment: Awesome.... Working Fine . Thanks Bro for saving time. Creator Bless you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a module I made, ngClipboard. Here's the link https://github.com/nico-val/ngClipboard

You can use either `ng-copyable` directive, or the `ngClipboard.toClipboard()` factory.

Comment: Thanks for the example but it doesn't seem to work in Safari.

Comment: Excellent work, legend. Just saved my day with `ng-copyable` directive.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML:

```
<a href="#" ><img src="/Images/copy.png" ng-click="copyToClipboard("TEXT_YOU_WANTTO_COPY")"></img></a>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.copyToClipboard = function (name) {
    var copyElement = document.createElement("textarea");
    copyElement.style.position = 'fixed';
    copyElement.style.opacity = '0';
    copyElement.textContent =  decodeURI(name);
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(copyElement);
    copyElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    body.removeChild(copyElement);
}
```

Comment: `document.execCommand` is not working now. Refer @fullstack answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app.service('ngCopy', ['$window', function ($window) {
    var body = angular.element($window.document.body);
    var textarea = angular.element('<textarea/>');
    textarea.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        opacity: '0'
    });

    return function (toCopy) {
        textarea.val(toCopy);
        body.append(textarea);
        textarea[0].select();

        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            if (!successful)
                throw successful;
           
        } catch (err) {
            window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", toCopy);
        }
        textarea.remove();
    }
}]);
```

You need to call this service to your controller. You can do like this:

```
controllers.MyController = ['$scope', 'ngCopy',
function ($scope, ngCopy) {
      ngCopy(copyText);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

For AngularJS

```
<!--The text field-->
<input type="text" ng-model="yourModel" id="helloWorld">

<!--The button used to copy the text-->
<button onclick="copyText()">Copy text</button>


function copyText() {
   var text = document.getElementById("helloWorld");
   text.select();
   text.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(text.value);
}
```