# How to display tooltip when content is copied to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to copy text to clipboard on click of button.

I am using below library for this but the only things lacking with that library is that it is not shown how to display tooltip when content is copied:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-clipboard

I have tried answers from below questions but those answer doesn't seems to work so i ended up using this above library:

[AngularJS copy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267589/angularjs-copy-to-clipboard)

[how to get clipboard data in angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028578/how-to-get-clipboard-data-in-angular-js)

I want to show my tooltip exactly the way as shown on this below question answer:

[Tooltips + Highlight Animation With Clipboard.js Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381640/tooltips-highlight-animation-with-clipboard-js-click)

Comment: where do you want to show the tooltip ?

Comment: @Alok I have updated my question to include the positionl where i want to display my tooltip

Answer (score 1):

So I kinda got it working.

Unfortunately we have to use some js to do it if you resort to using bootstrap tooltips.

Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VXPMnqWhmVT1ptSgiPKI?p=preview) that solves the problm.

Basically, boils down to these few lines of code:

```
 var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#copyButton' ) );
  myEl.attr('title', 'Copied!')
      .tooltip('fixTitle')
      .tooltip('show');

  myEl.attr('title',"Copied");

  myEl.on('hidden.bs.tooltip', function () {
    // do something…
    myEl.attr('title', $scope.copyButtonToolTip)
          .tooltip('fixTitle');
  });
```

Also, you should be using bootstrap version 3 instead of v4.

[Updated Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kUbirUOrlCmduGWPUFWO?p=preview)

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but when i copied once and then when i hover to that button it always shows copied but is it possible to create functionality like shown on this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381640/tooltips-highlight-animation-with-clipboard-js-click

Comment: Thanks alot for the updated plunker but i dont want to mix angular js and jquery so is it possible to handle all this things in a directive though that directive will use jquery?